# Unresolved external symbols in qtmaind.lib

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2015, qt5.6

I am trying to upgrade my Qt-project settings from Visual Studio 2013 to 2015. It almost done but I get some errors with qtmaind.lib.

> 1>qtmaind.lib(qtmain_winrt.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol **imp__RoInitialize@4 referenced in function _WinMain@16
>   1>qtmaind.lib(qtmain_winrt.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol __imp__RoGetActivationFactory@12 referenced in function
>   "public: __thiscall AppContainer::AppContainer(void)"
>   (??0AppContainer@@QAE@XZ) 1>qtmaind.lib(qtmain_winrt.obj) : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WindowsCreateStringReference@16
>   referenced in function "private: void __thiscall
>   Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::HStringReference::CreateReference(wchar_t
>   const *,unsigned int,unsigned int)"
>   (?CreateReference@HStringReference@Wrappers@WRL@Microsoft@@AAEXPB_WII@Z)
>   1>qtmaind.lib(qtmain_winrt.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol _WindowsDeleteString@4 referenced in function "public: void
>   __thiscall Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::HString::Release(void)" (?Release@HString@Wrappers@WRL@Microsoft@@QAEXXZ)
>   1>qtmaind.lib(qtmain_winrt.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol _WindowsGetStringRawBuffer@8 referenced in function "public:
>   wchar_t const * __thiscall
>   Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::HString::GetRawBuffer(unsigned int *)const "
>   (?GetRawBuffer@HString@Wrappers@WRL@Microsoft@@QBEPB_WPAI@Z)
>   1>qtmaind.lib(qtmain_winrt.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol _RoOriginateError@8 referenced in function "public: static void
>   __cdecl Microsoft::WRL::ErrorHelper<0>::OriginateError(long,struct HSTRING** *)"
>   (?OriginateError@?$ErrorHelper@$0A@@WRL@Microsoft@@SAXJPAUHSTRING__@@@Z)

Qt 5.6-rc (22-Feb-2016 15:11)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

link to WindowsApp.lib. That should resolve your issues.

Answer (score 2):

At least for getting GetActivationFactory, you need to link to runtimeobject.lib.